# How to allow outgoing SSH properly?

Tags: ssh, iptables

I am trying to allow outgoing SSH, but it doesn't work for some reason. I opened the port 22 for OUTPUT.

[Here is my script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03oaP.png)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide answers to [well-asked questions](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). This question could be improved by letting us know the operating system you're working with, what errors you're getting and what solutions you tried. Also, please include your script as a code block instead of an image. Have a look at [this article](http://superuser.com/help/formatting) for help on formatting your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script opens incoming SSH connections, not outgoing.

The input line for SSH is useless, it will be handled by the established / related rule. The output line for SSH needs to be `--dport 22`.